# Resize image in cppflow tensorflow c++

Tags: tensorflow, cppflow

Using cppflow, I have a 224x224 jpeg that I am trying to resize to 128x128.

```
auto input = cppflow::decode_jpeg(cppflow::read_file(std::string(filename)));
auto resized = cppflow::resize_bicubic(input,tensor({128,128}),true);
resized = cppflow::cast(resized, TF_UINT8, TF_FLOAT);
resized = input / 255.f;
resized = cppflow::expand_dims(input, 0);
```

However, I get the error:

> libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type
> std::runtime_error: input must be 4-dimensional[224,224,3]

Not sure how to turn this into a 4 dimensional array.

It expects: ''images: 4-D with shape [batch, height, width, channels].'' see documentation [here](https://docs.w3cub.com/tensorflow_cpp%7E2.4/class/tensorflow/ops/resize-bilinear.html).

I might be open to another method or solution if this is too unwieldy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out expand dims needs to be called earlier:

```
auto input = cppflow::decode_jpeg(cppflow::read_file(std::string(filename)));
input = cppflow::expand_dims(input, 0);
auto resized = cppflow::resize_bicubic(input, tensor({128,128}),true);
resized = cppflow::cast(resized, TF_UINT8, TF_FLOAT);
resized = resized / 255.f;
```